# Alinhando elementos lado a lado corretamente

Tags: html, css, float

Não estou conseguindo alinhar elementos lado a lado corretamente
A **DiV** fica como se estivesse com **Height: 0;** 
Apenas reconhecendo a altura do elemento sem o **Float: left;**
[image: ERRADO]

[image: CERTO]

HTML

A primeira é como ficou.
A segunda como tinha de ficar.

```
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trabalhos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #4B4B4B;
}

div#top-bar {

background-color: #f14949;
padding: 25px 80px 25px 80px;
}

div#logo {
vertical-align: middle;
float: left;
width: 86px;
height: 51px;
background-color: #4B4B4B;
border-radius: 6px;
}
nav#menu {

text-align: right;
}
nav#menu ul {
list-style: none;
}

nav#menu li {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Steve, não duplique perguntas, você pode sempre [**editar**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/102274/edit) uma pergunta e adicionar-lhe mais informações clicando no botão `editar` por baixo da sua publicação, em vez de criar novas perguntas que são repetidas. Eu adicionei lá uma resposta na sua pergunta original. Dê lá uma olhada. Bem-vindo :)

Comment: Desculpas, eu tentei tentei editar, e até mesmo excluir o outro post antes de fazer esse mas não consegui :(. E muito obrigado de novo.

Comment: Os botões - `editar`, `excluir` estão por baixo de cada publicação (pergunta/resposta) logo após as `tags` da pergunta. Mas se fores apagar uma das perguntas, apaga esta, pois eu já editei a outra com as informações adicionais que aqui adicionas-te e também por já lá ter adicionado uma resposta, por ter sido a original.